# Flutter : refresh page after return from next page to run function

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, page-refresh

I have first page contain function executed in initial statement getting data from server and used this data in this page,
when i navigate to second screen then third screen ,the data get by function changes ,therefore i want to execute that function again when return to first page to get new data again:

the function in first page :

```
void getUserStatus() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      username = preferences.getString('username');
      userId = preferences.getString('logined_id');
      lang = preferences.getString('lang');
    });
    var url =
        "http://xxxx/api/controller/users/status_user.php?username=$username";
    var response = await http.get(url);
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    setState(() {
      savedCourseId = data['m_id'];
      savedDayId = int.parse(data['d_id']);
    });
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    getUserStatus();

    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So all you have to do is use wherever you call push to Screen 2 use these

```
await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=> YourScreen2()));
await getUserStatus();
```

This will tell that some data is comming and we have to wait till you come back here and when you come back again you can use this data

Well you can also try to get some other data from the screen too
If you need more help you can go [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data)

Comment: if i am using named rout like this : Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('weeks', arguments: {
                  'courseId': courseId,
                  'lang': lang,
                  'savedDayId': savedDayId,
                  'savedCourseID': int.parse(savedCourseId),
                  'userID': userID,
                });

Answer (score 0):

Use async/await pattern for navigating to second screen.

```
_navigateToNextPage(BuildContext context) async {
// Navigator.push returns a Future that completes after calling
// Navigator.pop on the 2nd screen Screen.
await Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()));

// After the 2nd screen returns.
getUserStatus();
}
```